# WebApi Serializing to Json with POST Request

Tags: json, asp.net-core, serialization, swagger

I have the following WebApi controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class FunctionController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<FunctionController> _logger;
    private readonly IServiceAccessor<IFunctionManagementService> _functionManagementService;

    public FunctionController(
        IServiceAccessor<IFunctionManagementService> FunctionManagementService,
        ILogger<FunctionController> logger)
    {
        _functionManagementService = FunctionManagementService;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [SwaggerOperation(nameof(RegisterFunction))]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status200OK, "OK", typeof(FunctionRegisteredResponseDto))]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, "Bad Request")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterFunction(RegisterFunctionDto rsd)
    {
        var registeredResponse = await _functionManagementService.Service.RegisterFunctionAsync(rsd);
        if (registeredResponse.Id > -1)
            return Ok(registeredResponse);

        return BadRequest(registeredResponse);
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    [SwaggerOperation(nameof(UnregisterFunction))]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status200OK, "OK")]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound, "Not Found")]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, "Bad Request")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UnregisterFunction(string sid)
    {
        if (!long.TryParse(sid, out long id))
            return new BadRequestObjectResult(new { message = "400 Bad Request", UnknownId = sid });

        if (!await _functionManagementService.Service.UnregisterFunctionAsync(id))
            return new NotFoundObjectResult(new { message = "404 Not Found", UnknownId = sid });

        return new OkObjectResult(new { Message = "200 OK", Id = id, Unregistered = true });
    }
}
```

I am attempting to test requests to this service using MSTest. First I merely want to send a request to the service, I have attempted to do this (using [this example](https://forums.asp.net/t/2148414.aspx?Transfer+Objects+and+Data+from+Client+App+to+WebAPI)) via

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task BuildObjectFromValidResponse()
{
    RegisterFunctionDto rsd = Utils.GetRegisterFunctionDtoObject();
    string serializedDto = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rsd);

    var inputMessage = new HttpRequestMessage()
    {
        Content = new StringContent(serializedDto, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    };
    inputMessage.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/Function", inputMessage.Content);

    // Also tried this.
    //HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Function", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rsd));
}

public class RegisterFunctionDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Movement { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public static class Utils
{
    private static Random random = new Random();

    public static string GetName(int length = 5)
    {
        StringBuilder resultStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        string dictionaryString = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            resultStringBuilder.Append(dictionaryString[random.Next(dictionaryString.Length)]);

        return resultStringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    public static RegisterFunctionDto GetRegisterFunctionDtoObject()
    {
        return new RegisterFunctionDto()
        {
            Name = GetName(),
            Instruction = random.Next() % 2 == 0 ? BuySell.Buy : BuySell.Sell,
            PriceMovement = Convert.ToDecimal(random.NextDouble()),
            Quantity = 100
        };
    }
}
```

But when I post this to the service, the received object is the default one, this is one with all default values. So in `RegisterFunction` I am receiving

```
rsd { Name = "", Movement = 0.0, Quantity = 0 }
```

*Q. How can I correctly serialize my object using Newtonsoft.Json and post to me service?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to create `HttpRequestMessage` if using `HttpClient.PostAsync`. Just construct content and send it.

```
RegisterFunctionDto rsd = Utils.GetRegisterFunctionDtoObject();
string serializedDto = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rsd);
var content = new StringContent(serializedDto, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");    

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/Function", content);
```

You can also be explicit in telling the action to bind to data from body of request

```
//...
public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterFunction([FromBody]RegisterFunctionDto rsd) {
    //...
}
```